# using Pod environment variable to connect to pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

In my AKS cluster I have 2 services (API and Redis DB). I want to connect to the Redis DB from the API pod.

I got the Redis Env using `kubectl exec redis-pod -- printenv` and the host variable is `REDIS_SERVICE_HOST`, is it possible to inject this env into the API deployment?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
env:
   - name: REDIS_HOST
     value: ${REDIS_SERVICE_HOST}:6379
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to connect directly to that redis-pod? If you just want to use redis, you should rather use a Service (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). That will provide you with a static DNS that you could use as ENV Variable without having to read it from the redis-pod first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the redis host IP in a configMap and use that as env

```
  export REDISHOST_IP=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  kubectl create configmap redishost --from-literal=REDISHOST=${REDISHOST_IP}
```

---

```
env:
- name: REDISHOST
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: redishost
      key: REDISHOST
```

A better approach would be to use kubernetes service to expose redis

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: redis
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
```

Note: in this example the redis pod need to have label `app: redis`

Then inject `redis.default.svc.cluster.local` as redis host in other pods using env.

You also use configMap to store `redis.default.svc.cluster.local` and use it as env.

```
kubectl create configmap redishost --from-literal=REDISHOST=redis.default.svc.cluster.local
```

---

```
env:
- name: REDISHOST
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: redishost
      key: REDISHOST
```

This way even if redis pod is restarted and pod IP changes the other pods connecting to redis is not impacted and no change would be necessary.